# Asp ToolkitScriptManager not know element in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have tried many solution online but I am unable to fix. First off all i check in bin and it contains the dll as you can see.

Here is my front end code

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" TagPrefix="asp">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Also I check the webconfig file and was unable to see any mistakes

```
<system.web>
  <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

How can I get the AjaxControlToolKit to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you included the https://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/ nuget?

Comment: Yes when I execute "Install-Package AjaxControlToolkit -Version 18.1.1"                                                                                  
         I get "Package 'AjaxControlToolkit.18.1.1' already exists in project 'erp_columbia'"

Comment: Is it the 'erp_columbia' project that gives you the error? What error do you get?

Comment: When I run the application I get the following error Severity Code Description Project File Line Category Suppression State
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'ToolkitScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'AjaxControlToolkit' (are you missing an assembly reference?) erp_columbia C:\Users\Junior\Desktop\columbia project\erp_columbia\erp_columbia\erp_columbia\compras\inventario.aspx.designer.cs 31 Compiler Active

Comment: Now I remember the ToolkitScriptManager was removed from AjaxContolToolkit in v15.1, 2016 Read this: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below I remember I removed ToolkitScriptManager in a project a couple of years ago, ScriptManager was nearly drop in replacement as I remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToolkitScriptManager` was removed from AjaxControlToolkit in v15.1.

Replace the `ToolkitScriptManager` with the ordinary asp.net webforms `ScriptManager`:
https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v7.x-and-below